# How to use Bootstrap 4 so that help text is 100% width but input field is not

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap form-groups i have label, input field and help text vertically stacked. How can I have the field width of my select to not be 100% width, but keep the help text 100% width

Set this up in https://jsfiddle.net/paultaylor/0y9uyn76/2/

I want the select to only be 30ch, and I tried adding this style to outer div but of course it is then applied to help as well.

So I then tried just adding the style to the select element but that broke the formatting for some reason putting the label and input on same row instead of different rows, this failed attempt is shown in the code below and the jsfiddle.

```
<div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div>
      <label for="debugLevel" id="debugLevellabel">
          Debug Log Level
      </label>
      <select class="custom-select" style="width:30ch" name="debugLevel" id="debugLevel" aria-describedby="debugLevelhelp">

              <option value="0">
                  Severe
              </option>
              <option selected="selected" value="1">
                  Warning
              </option>
              <option value="2">
                  Info
              </option>
              <option value="3">
                  Config
              </option>
              <option value="4">
                  Fine
              </option>
              <option value="5">
                  Finer
              </option>
              <option value="6">
                  Finest
              </option>

      </select>
  </div>
  <p id="debugLevelhelp" class="form-text text-muted">
      Sets how much logging is written to the debug log, increasing the log level can help Jthink identify the cause of any problems encountered in SongKong
  </p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div>
      <label for="ioDebugLevel" id="ioDebugLevellabel">
          Debug IO Log Level
      </label>
      <select class="custom-select" style="width:30ch" name="ioDebugLevel" id="ioDebugLevel" aria-describedby="ioDebugLevelhelp">

              <option value="0">
                  Severe
              </option>
              <option selected="selected" value="1">
                  Warning
              </option>
              <option value="2">
                  Info
              </option>
              <option value="3">
                  Config
              </option>
              <option value="4">
                  Fine
              </option>
              <option value="5">
                  Finer
              </option>
              <option value="6">
                  Finest
              </option>

      </select>
  </div>
  <p id="ioDebugLevelhelp" class="form-text text-muted">
      Sets how much logging is written to the debug log when SongKong reads files or saves changes to files, increasing the log level can help Jthink identify the cause of any problems encountered in SongKong
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the row class to put the label, select and help text in separate lines

Comment: @mbadeveloper can you modify the jsfiddle please for my understanding

Comment: You can surround the select with a div and apply the style 30ch to it, it resize the select without effect the order of the another controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following bootstrap structure code with bootstrap class `d-block` and `d-inline-block` without any inline css.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="d-block" for="debugLevel" id="debugLevellabel"> Debug Log Level </label>
  <div class="d-inline-block">
    <select class="custom-select" name="debugLevel" id="debugLevel" aria-describedby="debugLevelhelp">
      <option value="0"> Severe </option>
      <option selected="selected" value="1"> Warning </option>
      <option value="2"> Info </option>
      <option value="3"> Config </option>
      <option value="4"> Fine </option>
      <option value="5"> Finer </option>
      <option value="6"> Finest </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p id="debugLevelhelp" class="form-text text-muted"> Sets how much logging is written to the debug log, increasing the log level can help Jthink identify the cause of any problems encountered in SongKong </p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="d-block" for="ioDebugLevel" id="ioDebugLevellabel"> Debug IO Log Level </label>
  <div class="d-inline-block">
    <select class="custom-select" name="debugLevel" id="debugLevel" aria-describedby="debugLevelhelp">
      <option value="0"> Severe </option>
      <option selected="selected" value="1"> Warning </option>
      <option value="2"> Info </option>
      <option value="3"> Config </option>
      <option value="4"> Fine </option>
      <option value="5"> Finer </option>
      <option value="6"> Finest </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p id="debugLevelhelp" class="form-text text-muted"> Sets how much logging is written to the debug log, increasing the log level can help Jthink identify the cause of any problems encountered in SongKong </p>
</div>
```

## Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/0y9uyn76/4/

Comment: I havent come across this in Bootstrap help so,  does this automatically set combo width to min required for contents !?

Comment: Thankyou I am going to mark this as the correct answer because it automatically sets the combo to the correct size, so generally is a better solution that having to set a fixed sized.

Comment: Glad you got help from this.

Answer (score 1):

You can surround the select with a div and apply the style 30ch to it, it resize the select without effect the order of the another controls

```html
<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <label for="debugLevel" id="debugLevellabel">
                Debug Log Level
            </label>
      <div style="width:30ch">
        <select class="custom-select" name="debugLevel" id="debugLevel" aria-describedby="debugLevelhelp">

          <option value="0">
            Severe
          </option>
          <option selected="selected" value="1">
            Warning
          </option>
          <option value="2">
            Info
          </option>
          <option value="3">
            Config
          </option>
          <option value="4">
            Fine
          </option>
          <option value="5">
            Finer
          </option>
          <option value="6">
            Finest
          </option>

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="debugLevelhelp" class="form-text text-muted">
      Sets how much logging is written to the debug log, increasing the log level can help Jthink identify the cause of any problems encountered in SongKong
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <label for="ioDebugLevel" id="ioDebugLevellabel">
                Debug IO Log Level
            </label>
      <div style="width:30ch">
        <select class="custom-select" name="ioDebugLevel" id="ioDebugLevel" aria-describedby="ioDebugLevelhelp">

          <option value="0">
            Severe
          </option>
          <option selected="selected" value="1">
            Warning
          </option>
          <option value="2">
            Info
          </option>
          <option value="3">
            Config
          </option>
          <option value="4">
            Fine
          </option>
          <option value="5">
            Finer
          </option>
          <option value="6">
            Finest
          </option>

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="ioDebugLevelhelp" class="form-text text-muted">
      Sets how much logging is written to the debug log when SongKong reads files or saves changes to files, increasing the log level can help Jthink identify the cause of any problems encountered in SongKong
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```